# Load Settings : Cannot load settings from file '\CryptoChatApp.iml' Android Studio

Tags: android, xml

I opened my project to get this error:

```
Load Settings
            Cannot load settings from file 'C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\CryptoChatApp\CryptoChatApp.iml': ParseError at [row,col]:[22,46]
            Message: Les structures de document XML doivent commencer et se terminer dans la même entité.
            Please correct the file content
Load Settings
            Cannot load settings from file 'C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\CryptoChatApp\app\app.iml': ParseError at [row,col]:[339,35]
            Message: Les structures de document XML doivent commencer et se terminer dans la même entité.
            Please correct the file content
```

I have checked the files but there were no row 22 or row 339

and my syles.xml, colors.xml and strings.xml show some kind of this code:

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="Gradle: androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0@aar">
      <CLASSES>
        <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/c1ba4e2c3c5650859a042f3d8936895f/espresso-core-3.2.0/jars/classes.jar!/" />
        <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/c1ba4e2c3c5650859a042f3d8936895f/espresso-core-3.2.0/res" />
      </CLASSES>
      <JAVADOC>
        <root url="
```

also my layouts looks like this :

[image: layout]

please help!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure android studio is closed, and enter `.idea` folder.
Delete the `modules.xml` file (where the missing files are being referenced).
Open your project in Android studio and it will now generate the missing `*.iml` files, as-well as the `modules.xml` file.

You will no longer get the annoying popup!